# What is JAX-MS and where can I learn about it?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee

I saw a few job listings asking for expertise on JAX-MS; I have only heard about JAX-WS and JAX-RS so far.

Googling for JAX-MS didn't return anything.

Is this simply a spelling mistake or there is someone out there that knows what is JAX-MS?

[One Job asking for JAX-MS](http://www.cwjobs.co.uk/JobSeeking/Senior-Developer--Systems-Specialist-JAX-WS-JMS-JPA-EJB-SPRING_job48455318)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously there is no such thing. The company seems to have gone so far with buzzwords that they invented their own. Be alarmed by that.

The JAX (Java API for XML) options are:

- JAX-RPC (obsolete)
- JAX-WS
- JAX-RS (restful)
- JAXP (p stands for "parsing")
- JAXB (b stands for "binding")

Comment: Thanks, that was what I wanted to confirm  :)

Answer (score 0):

Its a spelling mistake, just see through their error and apply if you want to.

Comment: it is used twice. I wouldn't say it's just a typo

Comment: either way, its unlikely to be a developer that wrote the listing

Answer (score 0):

It could be JMX (Java Management Extensions). Even I had confused my client once saying they could JAX-MS for monitoring.